# Dynamically allocate max_allowed_packet size for current and already logged mysql sessions  - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running the mysql with a max_allowed_packet of 32 M (33554432). As I want to dynamically allocate 126M I have gone for the below option

```
set GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=132120576;
```

But the `show variables like '%max_allowed_packet%';` still Shows 32M only with the already logged mysql sessions but the new sessions are reflected with the new value.

```
max_allowed_packet                      | 33554432
```

Issue Details :
While restoring the dump file, I can see the source operation is hanging hence I gone for the above option but still it is in the same state. Can I dynamically do any changes and solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [max_allowed_packet from the client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html), it is not enforced at the server in that regard, the server variable is really meant for replication. The max is 1GB.

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=512M -p < my_big_dump.sql
```